# How can merge this two function into one efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
Its basically changing the color of the html row of the table according to 
the value present in c1...c5. The difference between both the function is 
that, in 2nd function I am trying to add the value of "%".

def get_env(lm,mid,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5):
    global tag
    x = []
    for item in lm:
        rnd_off = round(item)
        x.append(rnd_off)
    tag  += '''<tr><th>'''+mid+'''</th>'''
    for i in hey:
        if i <= c1:
            tag += '<td style="background-color:#229954">' + ' ' +  str(i)  + '</td>'
        elif i > c1 and i <= c2:
```

Can someone please tell me how can I merge this two function into one correct way with repeating much of code.

I can merge the code the but still repeating a little bit of code. Just need to know the correct way of doing that.

Can someone please tell me how can I merge this correct way with repeating much of code?

Comment: `def merged(lm,mid,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5): get_env(lm,mid,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5); get_virt_load(lm,mid,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)` there you go

Comment: @timgeb lol, I want to merge the above two function in two one.
For example:-
get_env(lm,mid,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) +  get_virt_load(lm,mid) -> One function without repeation of the code

Comment: Sure but what is your specific question? "Here is my code, I won't explain what it's supposed to do but please refactor it ASAP" is not an acceptable "question".

Comment: @timgeb Its basically changing the color of the html row of the table according to the value present in c1...c5. The difference between both the function is that, in 2nd function I am trying to add the value of "%"

Comment: @timgeb I have updated the question as well

Comment: @timgeb Apology to bother you, I answer my terrible question

Answer (score 0):

The functions should return a string, not add to a global variable. I think, colors are constants, do you really need to give c1..5 as arguments?
`hey` is not defined, I think, this should be `lm`?

```
COLORS = {
    c1: '#229954',
    c2: '#ABC878',
    c3: '#F9E79F',
    c4: '#FBD567',
    c5: '#F9C169',
    1e99: '#E67C73',
}

def format_table(lm, mid, row):
    tag  = ['<tr><th>{}</th>'.format(mid)]
    for item in lm:
        for v, color in sorted(COLORS.items()):
            if item < v:
                break
        tag.append(row.format(color, item))
    tag.append('</tr>')
    return ''.join(tag)

def get_env(lm, mid):
    return format_table(lm, mid,
        '<td style="background-color:{}">{:.0f}</td>'
    )

def get_virt_load(lm,mid):
    return format_table(lm, mid,
        '<td style="background-color:{}">{:.0f}%</td>'
    )
```

Comment: x  == hey, c1....c5 is not something I need to specify I need to change the bg of html cell according to load